# Moodle integrate to existing system

Tags: php, moodle

This is my first time working with Moodle. I need to integrate moodle our existing student management system. with same URL and user authentication (using existing user structures) to access moodle
I have a few questions:

1. How can we use SSO for this
2. Is it possible work with same URL and user authentication now we are used

if anyone has good resources please help me :)

Comment: I don't think so, but if you are able to migrate your existing table schema, to the moodle format, then you can do something...for that you need to study the moodle database schema and build a migration script based in your current database...lot of work!

Comment: I'd suggest you consult Moodle's documentation or something - Moodle isn't really a programming tool, and I can't say I've ever noticed a Moodle question here before.  What you're asking, though, is whether it's possible to reverse-engineer the authentication done by Moodle and reuse that in another application ... which may be against their Terms of Service.

Answer (score 0):

You must read moodle Authentication API documentation 
https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Development:Authentication_API

In the documentation you can authenticate users with an external  database.

If you want to use moodle database you could export schemas, or you could connect with the moodle database to get data, you need develop apis to get your moodle data.